# administrate multiple databases Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have multiple Databases in my project and I want include them in Sonata Admin dashboard to manage them I have created an entity manager for every database  in Doctrine configuration part in app\config\config.yml , so how could I achieve managing those Databases in sonata admin bundle

Comment: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html